# when executing unlink function in php,Is directory error is coming in linux

Tags: php, linux

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($csvExportFilePath) as $fileData) {
    $fileName = $fileData->getFileName();
    $fileModifiedTime = $fileData->getMTime();
    if ((time() - $fileModifiedTime) > 24 * 3600) {
        $fullFilePath = $csvExportFilePath . $fileName;
        unlink($fullFilePath);
    }
}
/* unlink(/var/cliscripts/data/testmineExport/pdf/..): Is a directory in /var/cliscripts/scheduler/testmine/testmine.clearexportfiles.php on line 31
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a directory you have to use the [rmdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) function.

You can check if `$fullFilePath` is a direcotry with the [is_dir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) function before.

Comment: i have to delete files in directory

Comment: Then check what $fullFilePath contains

Comment: directory along with filename

Comment: Filenime with extension? Is $fullFilePath exactly the filename.html (for example)

Comment: A hidden file? Maybe with a . at the beginning? (For Linux/Unix systems) What if you try $fullFilePath = $csvExportFilePath.".".$fileName; ?

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting any file in PHP check whether this file is exist or not using: **file_exists($fullFilePath)**. If it is exist **check the file permission** which can be delete.